# Not display data in Html view (shows only 'undefined' for data value)

Tags: jquery, html, json, asp.net-web-api2

I have a problem in displaying the data in Html view. I am created web api asp.net mvc project. In the web api controller we have created crud methods (get, post, put and delete). For example, i have following method in web api controller.

```
public IEnumerable<vGeneralLedger> GetAllPosting()
        {
            try
            {
                return _db.vGeneralLedgers.ToList();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw;
            }
        }
```

That method would be display all posting from database. I say 'would', because I don't get that in html. In html, i have following function:

```
function GetAllPosting() {
        jQuery.support.cors = true;
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost:xxxxx/api/GeneralLedgerJournal/',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                WriteResponse(data);
            },
            error: function (x, y, z) {
                alert(x + '\n' + y + '\n' + z);
            }
        });
    }


function WriteResponse(generalLedgerJournals) {
        $.each(generalLedgerJournals, function (index, generalLedgerJournal) {
            $("#GLJtable").append('<tr><td width="150px">' + generalLedgerJournal.Id +
                     '</td><td width="150px">' + generalLedgerJournal.NaturalBusinessYearId +
                    '</td><td width="150px">' + generalLedgerJournal.DocumentTypeId +
                    '</td>' + '<td width="150px">'
                    + generalLedgerJournal.AccountNo + '</td><td width="150px">' + generalLedgerJournal.PostingDate +
                    '</td><td width="150px">' + generalLedgerJournal.MaturityDate +
                    '</td><td width="150px">' + generalLedgerJournal.Description +
                    '</td><td width="150px">' + generalLedgerJournal.TotalDebit +
                    '</td><td width="150px">' + generalLedgerJournal.TotalCredit +
                    '</td><td width="150px">' + generalLedgerJournal.Balance + '</td><td width="50px">' + '</td></tr>');
        });
    }
```

In browser console (when I hit F12) i have json data as shown in figure (link):

https://www.dropbox.com/s/htn5lav9g12c57r/Json%20Result.jpg?dl=0

But in Html View (Cshtml)  i get always displayed  'undefined' for value data, as shown in figure (link):
https://www.dropbox.com/s/oi52caemjlx9ed3/My%20result%20always%20undefined.jpg?dl=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 'digging' on my profile, I find the posts I have posted.
The answer of this question is (if we using angular), it is necessary to create an angular service (which use $http.get method) that will access to the web service (web api or mvc controller). After that, we can create angular controller and inject angular service to this controller. We can create function in controller which will call the metod from injected angular service. scope object or array in the controller must be equivalent for the variables in html page.